# Why does a secondary INNER JOIN limit results

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have three tables, like this:

**Parents**

```
| id  | title    |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | Parent 1 |
| 2   | Parent 2 |
```

**Relationships**

```
| parent_id | child_id |
| --------- | -------- |
| 1         | 1        |
```

**Children**

```
| id  | title   |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | Child 1 |
```

And I run the following query:

```
SELECT parents.title, 
       relationships.child_id 
FROM   parents 
       LEFT JOIN relationships 
              ON parents.id = relationships.parent_id 
       INNER JOIN children 
               ON relationships.child_id = children.id;
```

Why does it return the following?

```
| title    | child_id |
| -------- | -------- |
| Parent 1 | 1        |
```

I would expect it to return all parents (since there's a `LEFT JOIN` on the parents), and only return relationships if the child exists (since there's an `INNER JOIN` there).

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/djGTrJ7BDAHXaUJbWT8b44/0)

Comment: It's because of the `inner join` on the `children` table.  Use an `outer join` there as well and you'll get your expected results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT p.title, r.child_id 
FROM parents p LEFT JOIN
     relationships r
     ON p.id = r.parent_id INNER JOIN
     children c
     ON r.child_id = c.id;
--------^
```

The first `LEFT JOIN` might find no matching relationships for a given parent.  When this happens, `r.child_id` is `NULL`.  Obviously there is no match for the `INNER JOIN`, so the row is filtered out.

That is why `LEFT JOIN`s are usually chained.  Once you have one, you continue with the additional ones:

```
SELECT p.title, r.child_id 
FROM parents p LEFT JOIN
     relationships r
     ON p.id = r.parent_id LEFT JOIN
     children c
     ON r.child_id = c.id;
```

Comment: I would have thought that in the case of the `INNER JOIN`, "left" would be `r` and "right" would be `c`. So if `c` is missing, it would merely eliminate `r` but still return `p`. But are you saying it considers the entire row to be the "left" value in question here?

Comment: @Pete . . . `JOIN`s are interpreted left-to-right.  So your original logic is ((p left join r) inner join c).

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result by explicitly grouping your joins with parentheses:

```
SELECT parents.title, 
   relationships.child_id 
FROM   parents 
   LEFT JOIN (relationships 
              INNER JOIN children 
                  ON relationships.child_id = children.id)
       ON parents.id = relationships.parent_id
```

Note that `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN` has been moved to the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you have a `LEFT JOIN relationships` in your query, but you also have an `INNER JOIN children`, that eventually prevents non-matching rows to be  selected.

Try this instead :

```
SELECT parents.title, 
       relationships.child_id 
FROM   parents 
       LEFT JOIN relationships 
              ON parents.id = relationships.parent_id 
       LEFT JOIN children 
               ON relationships.child_id = children.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `inner join` is on the children table. Try it using an `outer join` it will return all of the parents.